# What is 'schizo culture'?

Tags: literary-theory

I read this term in Jameson, Deleuze wrote about "schizos", and it seems to have some parlance in literary theory in general.

What is 'schizo culture'?

Is there no such thing, is that the point of the phrase?

Comment: To Marxist Jameson, the postmodern media culture of capitalism is a disease that presents "*isolated, disconnected, discontinuous material signifiers which fail to link up into a coherent sequence*", just as schizophrenic experience does. To Deleuze and Guattari, on the other hand, "*schizophrenia is not the identity of capitalism, but on the contrary its difference, its divergence, and its death*", more of a solution than a problem, see 
[Towards a Radical Anti-Capitalist Schizophrenia? by Peretti](http://criticallegalthinking.com/2010/12/21/towards-a-radical-anti-capitalist-schizophrenia/).

Comment: good and provocative comment, thanks @Conifold

Comment: Distinguish, Schizoid Personality Disorder: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schizoid_personality_disorder